# get all object json data in view using ASP.NET MVC and JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, json-deserialization

I created a .json file which contain tourist places of a city. My json file look like this-

```
{
 "city":[
 {
 "Name": "Flensburg Firth",
 "Shorttext": "Flensburg Firth or Flensborg Fjord ....",
 "Longitude": 9.42901993,
 "Latitude": 54.7959404,
 "Image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/Flensborg_Fjord_ved_bockholmwik.jpg/400px-Flensborg_Fjord_ved_bockholmwik.jpg"
 },


 {
 "Name": "Naval Academy Mürwik",
  "Shorttext": "The Naval Academy Mürwik is the main train....",
 "Longitude": 9.45944444,
 "Latitude": 54.815,
 "Image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/MSM-hauptgebaeude.jpg/400px-MSM-hauptgebaeude.jpg"

 },
 {   
 "Name": "Nordertor",
 "Shorttext": "The Nordertor is an old town gate in Flensburg, Germany....",
 "Longitude": 9.43004861,
 "Latitude": 54.79541778,
  "Images":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Nordertor_im_Schnee_%28Flensburg%2C_Januar_2014%29.JPG/266px-Nordertor_im_Schnee_%28Flensburg%2C_Januar_2014%29.JPG"

 }

]
```

}

My Model class to get the object for this json data is -

```
 public class City
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Shorttext { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

 }
 public class RootObject
 {

    public List<City> city { get; set; }
 }
```

Now in controller I create actionresult to return view in view bag message-
// I have edited contrller class

```
    public ActionResult GMap(City objCityModel)
    {

        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        ViewBag.Title = name;


        var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/"+name+".json"));

       RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(ReadJson);



        foreach (var item in json.poi)
        {

            ViewBag.Name = item.Name;
            ViewBag.ShortText = item.Shorttext;
            ViewBag.Latitude = item.Latitude;
            ViewBag.Longitude = item.Longitude;
            ViewBag.Image = item.Image;
        }

    return View();
```

My GMap.cshtml is -

```
@model  Test2_search.Models.City


@{
ViewBag.Title1 = "Google Map View";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<p>@ViewBag.ShortText</p>
<p>@ViewBag.Latitude</p>
<p>@ViewBag.Longitude</p>
<p>@ViewBag.Image</p>
```

With this code I can get only first object of that json file. like only data for  "Flensburg Firth". but I want to show the all three places in that city in view. How can i get all the deserialized json data in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Lit<City> mycities=new List<City>();
     foreach (var item in json.poi)
    {
        City obj=new City(){
        Name = item.Name,
        ShortText = item.Shorttext,
        Latitude = item.Latitude,
        Longitude = item.Longitude,
        Image = item.Image,
         };
       mycities.Add(obj);
    }
```

// You can even have this in your ViewModel

```
     ViewBag.Cities=mycities;
```

And in your view 
        @Foreach(var city viewBag.Cities){
        //Bind ur data
          }

Hope this steps could help

Comment: you are doing double work here.  You've already defined city as a List<City>. There's no reason to copy it into a new object.  Just return json.poi.
like this
ViewBag.Cities=json.poi;

Comment: ViewBag.Cities=json.poi.city; I think this would be more accurate with minimal lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all : [`.First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) always returns only one element or exception.

To get all Names You can :

- Show cities in list/table passing to view model as `RootObject` and in view loop through every item in `RootObject.city`
- Join all Names using [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method and pass them to View with ViewBag as You did.

Example `String.Join(", ",json.city.Select(c => c.Name);` => Output : `London, New York, Paris`

---

About "always getting last element" : 
this Code will return only last element.

```
    foreach (var item in json.poi)
    {

        ViewBag.Name = item.Name;
        ViewBag.ShortText = item.Shorttext;
        ViewBag.Latitude = item.Latitude;
        ViewBag.Longitude = item.Longitude;
        ViewBag.Image = item.Image;
    }
```

Cause at first iteration your `ViewBag.Name` will contain first element name. At second iteration you override `ViewBag.Name` value to secon element name. So at the end you will get last element name

Comment: I have edited my controller class. but now I get the last one. Could you please explain how can i get all the three values. I am really struggling a lot about this issue for two days. thank you

Comment: But I am not getting any way to show all the result accordingly. I have browsed 100 times all the site. but have not got any perfect solution for this .

Answer (score 0):

Change your View to this

```
    @model  Test2_search.Models.City


    @{
    ViewBag.Title1 = "Google Map View";
    }

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
    <h2>@item.Title</h2>
    <p>@item.ShortText</p>
    <p>@item.Latitude</p>
    <p>@item.Longitude</p>
    <p>@item.Image</p>
}
```

Change your controller action to this

```
    public ActionResult GMap()
    {

        var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/whateverthenameis.json"));

       RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(ReadJson);

   return View(json.city);
}
```

I'm not sure where json.poi came into play.  I don't see that you've defined it in your model.